# What does it mean in documentation when arguments are in square brackets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, documentation

When I'm reading documentation I don't understand what it means when function parameters are in square brackets.

Taking for example OpenCV's `GaussianBlur` function:

```py
cv2.GaussianBlur(src, ksize, sigmaX[, dst[, sigmaY[, borderType]]]) → dst
```

What do the square brackets just after `sigmaX`, mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means optional arguments.

It is not python specific syntax, it is more general grammar notation syntax, for example, from [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus–Naur_form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form):

> Many BNF specifications found online today are intended to be human-readable and are non-formal. These often include many of the following syntax rules and extensions:
>
> Optional items enclosed in square brackets: [].

Better explanation in [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus–Naur_form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form), `Basics` chapter.